# How to create a service without any /system/etc/init.d directory

Tags: boot, scripts, services

I would to get a boot daemon service.

My android 6 device is rooted and I installed busybox pack on it. After remount my `/system` partition in read/write, I make `/system/etc/init.d` directory  and I put my shell script inside. I rebooted my android device and the script didn't start alone. I checked the executable permission as well.

I browse the web around the question and I should modify my `/init.rc` file trough modify the `boot.img` file and this is a few complicate and `init.rc` seems target one file not a directory.

Is there an other procedure?
Thank for your help.

Comment: You need to flash a custom kernel that supports the **init.d** functionality. Only then will you be able to start scripts at boot. Editing **init.rc** should be your last strategy, as it's more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here :
[How to Enable Init.d Support on most Android](http://www.theandroidhow.com/2014/06/how-to-enable-initd-support-on-android.html)

That's worked for me